# Containers and HTTP caching in the host OS

Tags: docker, containers, http-caching

I think there's a downside with very short-lived containers.

My understanding is that when an application runs inside a container, it sees a virtualised file-system (Docker does copy-on-write). Thus, mutations to the file-system are volatile.

This means that >1 containers on a big VM will not share the HTTP cache. More tangibly, on Windows since that's my domain, any writes to the WinInet cache will be isolated.

If I were to configure the OS to place the cache in a shared location, a data volume, would I now encounter locking issues where >1 HTTP OS subsystems are all trying to write to the same cache?

Probably not...

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wndp/2006/08/04/a-bit-about-wininets-index-dat/

How else could we design for 1,000s of transient containers to benefit from the same cache?

- Move the Temporary Internet Files to a data volume.
- Reverse proxy with caching.
- Output caching in the web server.

The nice thing about OS caching is that the request never hits the wire.

Comment: Are you using any sort of orchestration technology here e.g. Kubernetes, ECS? Any requirements cache-purging/updating across all nodes?

Comment: Hey Rob. I'm not sure it matters. Just to be clear, this is about the "invisible" utilisation of local OS HTTP caching, a huge scaling benefit. This benefit is lost if the container and cache lifetime are the same, and the container lifetime is very short. The local HTTP cache will never have time to build-up and be of use.